# Podman stop command removes container

Tags: podman

I am having a container say "hello" which I am trying to start, stop and restart using podman commands.

[ **podman version : 3.3.1** on **RHEL** ]

I am running this commands:

1. `podman start hello`
2. `podman stop hello`
3. `podman start hello`

The third command gives error as:

```
Error: no container with name or ID "hello" found: no such container
```

I ran ***podman ps*** and ***podman ps -a*** to check running and available containers resp. But none displays the "hello" container.

I found out this link of bug someone raised earlier on github, though I am not using "--rm" command and still getting this issue.

[Podman stop removes the container](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/13861)

Anything am I missing here or any more info needs to be added to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers are not automatically removed when you stop them unless you create the container using the `--rm` flag.

You didn't specify how you created your `hello` container. When creating it, are you passing `--rm` to `podman create`? The behavior you are describing corresponds to the scenario of creating a container with the `--rm` flag.

###### `AutoRemove`

If you want to know whether the host will automatically remove a given container after exiting, then check the `AutoRemove` boolean field of the `HostConfig` object:

```
podman inspect --format \
 'automatically remove: {{if .HostConfig.AutoRemove}}yes{{else}}no{{end}}' \
 hello
```

This will display either `automatically remove: yes` or `automatically remove: no`.

---

##### Example with `--rm`

We create the following container `hello` with the `--rm` flag:

```
podman create --rm --name hello alpine sleep 5000
```

We can check with `podman ps -a` that the `hello` container exists and has the status *created*.

We can also check that the `AutoRemove` field is set to true:

```
$ podman inspect --format '{{.HostConfig.AutoRemove}}' hello
true
```

Then, we start the container with `podman start hello`. You can check that the container is running with `podman ps`.

If you now stop the container with `podman stop hello`, you won't be able to see it any longer on the container list provided by `podman ps -a`. That is, the container has been **automatically removed**.

---

##### Example without `--rm`

If we repeat the same process, but without the `--rm` flag at the moment of creating the `hello` container, the container won't be automatically removed when it is stopped this time:

1. Create the container without passing `--rm`:

   ```
   podman create --name hello alpine sleep 5000
   ```

   Check that the `AutoRemove` field is set to false:

   ```
   $ podman inspect --format '{{.HostConfig.AutoRemove}}' hello
   false
   ```
2. Start it:

   ```
   podman start hello
   ```
3. Stop it:

   ```
   podman stop hello
   ```

   You can check now with `podman ps -a` that the container still exists.
4. Restart it:

   ```
   podman restart hello
   ```

This time, if you want to remove the container, you need to manually do it:

```
podman container rm -f hello
```

Comment: I am pulling the container from brew. And then using it. I am not sure how to find how the container was generated. I went through a issue raised in GitHub and there the person did the same (generating using --rm). So i am aware of that issue. I am looking for any other possibility of failing.

Comment: @ShivamPapat what you are pulling is an image, right? and from that image, you are creating a container. How do you actually create that container?

Comment: @ShivamPapat Please, try out `podman inspect --format '{{.Config.CreateCommand}}' hello` to see whether you can find out how the container was created.

Comment: @ShivamPapat I've edited the answer. What you need to know is the value of `.HostConfig.AutoRemove`. It will actually tell you whether or not the container will be removed by the host after exiting.

Comment: I checked the auto-remove property of another container. Tt was false, so I changed it to true and tried to (start-stop-start), it started.
Seems like it does not make any difference!

Answer (score 1):

I will write what command worked for me.
(Thanks to @[ネロク](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8012646/%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AD%E3%82%AF) for the helpful command)

In my case I already have container present in the machine. The only way to find how it run was with command

```
podman inspect --format '{{.HostConfig.AutoRemove}}' hello
```

Output:

true --> container was run with --rm parameter
`podman run -d --rm hello`

false--> container was run without --rm paramter `podman run -d hello`

For first case, when you'll stop container, it'll be actually removed from your machine.
And thus while trying to start container after stopping it will give error,

```
 podman start hello
 Error: no container with name or ID "hello" found: no such container
```